# Asp.Net MVC3 Upload a new logo for page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, image, redirect, file-upload

In the application I'm working on I need to be able to upload a new logo for the site from a settings page. As of now the code replaces the logo-file on disk, but the `redirect` to the same settings page still shows the old image. Although after a refresh of the page I get the correct image.

I would like the `Redirect` to load the new image. 
I've set these values for the ImageHeaders:

```
    response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
    response.Cache.SetExpires(Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration);
    response.Cache.SetLastModified(File.GetLastWriteTime(FileName));
```

Are there some sort of "stronger" `redirect`, or some other way to make this possible?